# SQLAlchemy - Dependency rule tries to blank-out primary key column of deleted object

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Here is an example code that demonstrates my problem:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, create_engine, Integer
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, relationship, backref
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import event, ForeignKey, and_

Base = declarative_base()

class A(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'as'
    aid = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

class F(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'fs'
    fid = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

class G(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'gs'
    aid = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('as.aid'), primary_key=True)
    fid = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('fs.fid'), primary_key=True)
    a = relationship('A')
    f = relationship('F')

class X(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'xs'
    aid = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('as.aid'), primary_key=True)
    fid = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('fs.fid'), primary_key=True)
    a = relationship('A')
    f = relationship('F')
    g = relationship('G', primaryjoin="and_(X.aid==G.aid, X.fid==G.fid)", foreign_keys=[aid, fid], backref=backref('active', uselist=False))

e = create_engine("sqlite://", echo=True)
Base.metadata.create_all(e)

sm = sessionmaker(bind=e, expire_on_commit=False)
s = sm()

a = A(aid=1)
s.add(a)
s.commit()

f = F(fid=1)
s.add(f)
s.commit()

g = G()
g.a = a
g.f = f
s.add(g)
s.commit()

g.active = X()
g.active.a = a
g.active.f = f
s.add(g.active)
s.commit()

# Goal: delete g.active. under some conditions, delete g.a and g as well

s.delete(g.active)
s.commit()
s.delete(g.a)
s.commit()
g.active = None
s.delete(g)
s.commit()  # Dependency rule tried to blank-out primary key column 'xs.aid' on instance '<X at 0x3f89230>'
```

Question: How can I delete g.a and g, after already deleting g.active, without getting this error? Do I need some kind of cascade?

Please note that I don't always want to delete g.a and g in my real application (it is variable), so I don't want a cascade that will always delete them.

Comment: [Similar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35040724/5320906)?