# What could be the cause of "Dependency rule tried to blank-out primary key column"

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

When im trying to delete category instance identified by 'id' with its category_image and files instances the way like this:

```
c = Category.query.get(id)
for ci in c.images:
    db.session.delete(ci)
db.session.flush()
for ci in c.images:
    db.session.delete(ci.file)
db.session.flush()  # if i type here db.session.commit() all is fine
db.session.delete(c)
db.session.commit()
```

i'm getting a AssertionError: Dependency rule tried to blank-out primary key column 'category_image.id_category' on instance ''. But when i replace flush which is after deleting category_image.files with commit, then it works. I've notice it after i changed CategoryImage table to intermediary. Before changes it has it's own pk that wasn't combined and all was working properly. Here're my current models definitions.

```
class File(db.Model):                              
    __tablename__ = 'file'                                    

    id_file = Column(Integer, Sequence('seq_id_file'), primary_key=True, nullable=False)                                
    name = Column(Text, nullable=False)                       
    path = Column(Text, nullable=False, unique=True)                       
    protected = Column(Boolean, nullable=False, default=False)


class Category(db.Model):                                                           
    __tablename__ = 'category'                                                                 

    id_category = Column(Integer, Sequence('seq_id_category'), primary_key=True, nullable=False)                                                         
    name = Column(UnicodeText, nullable=False, unique=True)                                         
    images = relationship('CategoryImage', backref='images')                                   


class CategoryImage(db.Model):                                                      
    __tablename__ = 'category_image'                                                           
    __table_args__ = (                                                                         
    PrimaryKeyConstraint('id_category', 'id_file', name='seq_id_category_image'),          
    )                                                                                          

    id_category = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Category.id_category), nullable=False)             
    id_file = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(File.id_file), nullable=False)                                      
    id_size_type = Column(Integer, nullable=)                                                  
    file = relationship(File)
```

Now i'm trying to figure out what just happened. Correct me if i'm using things wrong.

Comment: Have you had a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23699651/dependency-rule-tried-to-blank-out-primary-key-in-sqlalchemy-when-foreign-key-c and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35040724/dependency-rule-tried-to-blank-out-primary-key-column-in-sql-alchemy-when-trying? It is the relationship cascades trying to null the foreign key upon parent's deletion. Though you've deleted them in the session, they're still sort of there (not so when you commit in between).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just noticed that i have to delete objects beeing in relation with intermediate model in the same order as it was declared in **table_args**, PrimaryKeyConstraint('id_category', 'id_file'). So when i perform it this way: session.delete(category_image), session.delete(category), session.delete(file) and commit it or flush everywhere before commit, then all works fine. If anyone spot something about it in alch docs let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what is happening. Once you call session.delete() on some object it is like having marked the object for deletion but not yet deleted from db. when you call the flush() after deleting (note: db still has the object as it is yet not committed) but session has marked the object as deleted. So the objects become inconsistent. In order to make the delete smooth you can always wrap your delete operations within a transaction and once they are deleted from the session you need to call the db.commit() once to make db session consistent with the db.
Hope it helps.

Comment: > you can always wrap your delete operations within a transaction
How do you do this with SQLAlchemy? It seems that the `Session` object is automatically doing this anyway, so how does one finely control that?